# Array to string in array

Tags: php

This is my array, but some values are empty array and i want to convert them into empty strings, but i'm not sure how. Try some solutions, but "can't convert array to string".

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(32) {
        ["product_id"]=>
        string(2) "30"
        ["name"]=>
        string(12) "Canon EOS 5D"
        ["model"]=>
        string(9) "Product 3"
        ["sku"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["upc"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["ean"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["jan"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["manufacturer_id"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["tax_class_id"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["points"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["quantity"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["minimum"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["isbn"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["mpn"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["stock_status_id"]=>
        string(1) "6"
      }
```

But i want these:

```
["sku"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["upc"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["ean"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["jan"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
```

to looks like this:

```
["sku"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["upc"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["ean"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["jan"]=>
        string(0) ""
```

a.k.a empty string, not arrays. That's it. Maybe some check if is empty array to convert to string, i'm not sure. Thank u!

Comment: `if (empty($a)) $a = "";`

Comment: just iterate over your array and check if the nested array is empty, then put an empty string in place of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach ($products['shopproduct'] as $product) {
        foreach ($product as $k => $v) {
            if (empty($v)) {
                $product[$k] = '';
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($products['shopproduct']);
```

The problem you're working with copy ($product) of an array in foreach.
You can use ampersand for reference like

```
foreach ($products['shopproduct'] as &$product) {
...
```

or

```
    foreach ($products['shopproduct'] as $j => $product) {
        foreach ($product as $k => $v) {
            if (empty($v)) {
                $products['shopproduct'][$j][$k] = '';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lol .. thank u, sir ! Can u explain me
foreach ($products['shopproduct'] as &$product) {
...

Comment: What exactly to explain?

Comment: &$product < this one

Comment: This is standart reference in php. All php variables have they own place in memory. When you're using $product in foreach without & then array value of $products['shopproduct'][$j] is copied to $product variable and original array is not touched.

When you're using ampersand then $products['shopproduct'][$j] value is not copied, but only reference to it in $product variable. So you can work with original array value.

Comment: try something like http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/references-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Just replace it with an empty string when the value is empty.

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if(empty($v)){
        $array[$k]='';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map`. Check below code:

```
$array2 = array_map(function($value) {
   return count($value) == 0 ? "" : $value;
}, $array);
```